# SQL Server Redundant Filter Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

I have a unique issue that I've never seen before. First I will simplify to see if there is any obvious answer. If necessary, I can post more details about the query/execution plan.

Edit: unable to attach actual execution plan. It's also huge so I can't paste XML. Sites are blocked at my company to save the file in a different location. I am hoping someone has seen this before and has a suggestion in what to look for.

I have a view that is essentially:

```
 Select A.Customer
       B.CustomerType
       c.SalesPersonName
       A.LineAmount 

 From FactOrder  A
 Join customer b on a.Customer = a.Customer
 Join SalesPerson c on a.SalesRepID = c.SalesRepID
```

I then have a script on top of the View. It first puts a list of customers in a variable table, usually a handful.

```
 Select v.Customer
  ,      SUM(v.lineamount) as Sales
 From View v
 Join @CustomerList c on v.customer = c.Customer
 Where v.Customer in (select Customer From @CustomerList)
 Group by v.Customer
```

I am using a Where **AND** a Join to filter, and I get almost instant results. If I only use 1 method, it just spins. Any ideas?

Comment: keeping getting an error when trying to add the rest of my question.. trying to figure it out.

Comment: What is `Where Customer` ? And I'm with @Siyual , I don't understand you.

Comment: I kept getting an error when trying to paste in the rest of my question. Full question there now.

Comment: make sure you're using your table aliases every time you call a field, you've got multiple tables with the field 'Customer'

Comment: Add both execution plans. And note that you have different @ in where and in join clauses.

Comment: Paste what?  I don't see anything different

Comment: `WHERE Customer IN (...` This should be throwing an error.  There are already two `Customer` fields defined in the query (in `View` and `@Customer`) and you don't have the alias prepended.

Comment: made my example more accurate

Comment: add both execution plans

Comment: @Ivan is there an easy way to do that ? I don't see a way to attach. An image won't work because the actual execution plans are pretty big and difficult to read..

Comment: `SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON` and attach xml. Or right-click on "actual plan" and "save plan as...".

Comment: @Ivan I mean attached to this stackoverflow post. I have the plans saved from SSMS

Comment: I don't know - "try to restart your computer". Write to support. There are many questions and answers with attaches and pictures embeddes as well.

Comment: I googled and there isn't a way to attach a file to a request. Would be curious to see one of the many you've seen. I can't paste the XML for the plan because it's huge. Tried a few random sites to add attachments but they're blocked at my company. I'm a little hesitant to post my company's DB schemas anyway. I guess i'm hoping for a suggestion in what to look for in an execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using table aliases everywhere that they're appropriate. You also don't need that where clause, it's already done in the INNER JOIN;

```
SELECT 
v.Customer
,SUM(v.ineamount) as Sales
FROM View v
JOIN @Customer c on v.customer = c.Customer
GROUP BY v.Customer
```

Comment: that is my question. I have the inner join to filter & the Where clause. If I leave both in the query, I get instant results. If I pick 1 of them, it spins & never finishes.

Comment: Run it with the actual execution plan switched on, what's the difference between your queries?

Comment: the plans are very different. If there's no obvious answer to my question, I will have to learn to to decipher the differences in execution plans and post again with more details. I'm going to try to do that today. Thanks